# Read XML value with Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

How do I read the XML value of the propertiy “d:EncodedAbsUrl” from the XMLstructure below using Javascript or Jquery. (Same problem with “m:Properties”).

Tried

```
var pics = $(xml).find("entry");
console.log(pics[0].content['\m:properties'].EncodedAbsUrl.innerHTML);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'm:properties' of undefined

and

```
var pics = $(xml).find("entry");
console.log(pics[0].content.properties.EncodedAbsUrl.innerHTML);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/_api/"
    <updated>2018-04-08T17:12:43Z</updated>
    <entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
        <id>12345</id>
        <category term="SP.Data.SlideshowItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'12345')/Items(1)" />
        <title />
        <updated>2018-04-08T17:12:43Z</updated>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:EncodedAbsUrl>https://GIVE.ME.THIS.URL.:O</d:EncodedAbsUrl>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
        <id>123456</id>
        <category term="SP.Data.SlideshowItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'123456')/Items(6)" />
        <title />
        <updated>2018-04-08T17:12:43Z</updated>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:EncodedAbsUrl>https://GIVE.ME.THIS.URL.:O</d:EncodedAbsUrl>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

**Edit 2018-04-12**
I went around the XML crap and requested the data as JSON instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should try an open library like [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to parse this XML as a JSON object and then look for the key you desire in the structure. A sample example is shown below

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escaped jQuery selectors when there is a special charactter like `:`

Try:

```
var pics = $(xml).find("entry");
pics.each(function(){
   var url = $(this).find('d\\:EncodedAbsUrl').text();
   console.log(url)
})
```

See [jQuery selector escaping rules](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score -1):

It may depend on how you are getting your XML; i.e. request, separate file, or setting a file string. If you are setting a file string you can do this.

```
var myXML = "your XML here",
    $xml = $( myXML );  // wrap your xml in jQuery.

   // then you can select the elements like this.
     var $absUrls = $xml.find.("d:EncodedAbsUrl"), // this will return an array of absUrls. 
           $properties = $xml.find("m:Properties"); // this returns an array of m:properties
```

.

This is based on the jQuery documentation.

[reading XML WITH JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)